# How can I use system or system2 if the command has pipe to head like "cmd | head"

Tags: r, system2

I noticed that when I run a long command in `linux` (I am using a cantos 7.3 distro, R 4.0.3 on the terminal) and that I pipe to `head` only the first outputs are shows to me (and the command stops)

```
ls -R /opt        # on my system I would get tons of output for 10s of seconds
ls -R /opt | head # just get the top 5 and command is stopped straight away
```

when I try the equivalent in R I cannot get the same behaviour

```
system(command = "ls -R /opt | head") # will take a long time (I assume the time for ls -R /opt to finish)
```

Is there a way for me to get the same behaviour in `R` than the one I get on my system command line ?

Comment: I don't see a slowdown here (using macOS 10.15.7), running R from the command line or R.app.  On RStudio it seems slower.  What is your OS and which R frontend are you using?

Comment: how fast is the command you're running finishes if you do not pipe to head ? sufficiently long so there is a difference when you pipe to head ?

Comment: Using `/opt` isn't very slow, but using `/users` is quite slow without piping.  Only see the slow pipe with RStudio.

Comment: (on windows) `system` doesn't honor the `|` piping mechanism, it's just another character passed to `ls` (and `ls` also sees `head` as an argument). (This isn't a factor on unix-like OSes)

Comment: ok good to know thanks, but as I said I am on linux. So the question remains unanswered